# How to remove \n and \r from a string

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, file-writing

I currently am trying to get the code from this website: http://netherkingdom.netai.net/pycake.html
Then I have a python script parse out all code in html div tags, and finally write the text from between the div tags to a file. The problem is it adds a bunch of \r and \n to the file. How can I either avoid this or remove the \r and \n. Here is my code:

```
import urllib.request
from html.parser import HTMLParser
import re
page = urllib.request.urlopen('http://netherkingdom.netai.net/pycake.html')
t = page.read()
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_data(self, data):
        print(data)
        f = open('/Users/austinhitt/Desktop/Test.py', 'r')
        t = f.read()
        f = open('/Users/austinhitt/Desktop/Test.py', 'w')
        f.write(t + '\n' + data)
        f.close()
parser = MyHTMLParser()
t = t.decode()
parser.feed(t)
```

And here is the resulting file it makes:

```
b'
import time as t\r\n
from os import path\r\n
import os\r\n
\r\n
\r\n
\r\n
\r\n
\r\n'
```

Preferably I would also like to have the beginning b' and last ' removed. I am using Python 3.5.1 on a Mac.

Comment: I'd say 3.x if urllib returns a bytes object

Comment: Also, `html.parser` is Python 3.

Comment: @RafaelCardoso I am using python 3.x

Comment: Just convert `t` to a string instead of a byte array; `t = str(page.read(), 'UTF-8')`. (optionally replacing UTF-8 with the encoding you want, of course)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson that seems to remove everything except the first line.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

A simple solution is to strip trailing whitespace:

```
with open('gash.txt', 'r') as var:
    for line in var:
        line = line.rstrip()
        print(line)
```

The advantage of `rstrip()` over using a `[:-2]` slice is that this is safe for UNIX style files as well.

However, if you only want to get rid of `\r` and they might not be at the end-of-line, then `str.replace()` is your friend:

```
line = line.replace('\r', '')
```

If you have a byte object (that's the leading `b'`) the you can convert it to a native Python 3 string using:

```
line = line.decode()
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I tried it and it doesn't change it.

Comment: There was a typo (OS  X corrective text), `strip` should have been `rstrip`.

Comment: It says that str object has no attribute decode. I do not convert the byte data to a string anywhere in the code so why do I get this error?

Comment: Also @cdarke I tried the replace code on \r and it doesn't work. All the \r's remain. I even tried it on other characters to ensure it works and it removed other characters it just won't remove \r or \n.

Comment: You should be using `decode()` on bytes objects, not string objects - you asked how to get rid of the `b'`  - that indicates a bytes object.  I don't understand why the `replace()` would not work, you are capturing the returned value I hope.  Remember that none of the Python string methods alter the string, they all return a new string (because strings are immutable).

Comment: oh, ok. Thanks! Let me fix that.

Comment: This saved my life. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

to remove carriage return:

- `line = line.replace('\r', '')`

to remove tab

- `line = line.replace('\t', '')`