# How can I append these word to array without \r\n

Tags: python

how to add each word in this structure to an array?

I want to remove the extra quotations an (\r\n)

```
for item in most_common_list:
    print(item[0])
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove \n and \r from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35830924/how-to-remove-n-and-r-from-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [strip()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_strip.asp) method on your strings to remove whitespace (includes `\r` and `\n`)

---

If it is the case that you have literal `\r` and `\n` strings in your text (as opposed to carriage return and newline characters), you should figure out why these are being generated and put into your `most_common_lost` and fix it at the source.  It seems highly likely that they should not be a part of these strings.

Comment: I am not able to remove them using strip()

Comment: Is it possible you have literal `\r` and `\n` strings in your text (as opposed to carriage return and newline characters)?  If so, you should figure out why these are being generated and fix it at the source.  If not, then strip() will work if you call it correctly.  How have you tried to use strip()?   How is your `most_common_list` list created?

Comment: As you suggested, I fixed it from the source and it works, thanks!